# Como calcular a soma de cada linha de uma matriz em C?

Tags: c, array, algoritmo, matriz

Preciso criar um algorítimo que leia as dimensões de uma matriz, leia os valores a serem colocados na matriz, com um vetor calcule a soma dos valores de cada linha e imprima a matriz e o vetor.

Este `float soma` calcula a soma total de toda a matriz, porém preciso calcular a soma de cada linha.

```
int main() {

    int L , C , linha = 0 , coluna = 0;
    float soma = 0;
    printf("\nDigite o numero de linhas da matriz: ");
    scanf("%d",&L);
    printf("\nDigite o numero de colunas da matriz: ");
    scanf("%d",&C);
    float matriz[L][C];


    for(linha = 0; linha < L; linha++){
        for(coluna = 0; coluna < C; coluna++){
            printf("\nDigite o %d valor para a %d linha: ",coluna + 1, linha + 1);
            scanf("%f",&matriz[linha][coluna]);
            soma = soma + matriz[linha][coluna];

        }
    }

    for (linha = 0; linha < L; linha++){
        for(coluna = 0; coluna < C; coluna++){
            printf("%5.2f ",matriz[linha][coluna]);
        }
            printf("\n\n");
    }



    printf("\n\nA soma total eh  %5.2f\n\n\n",soma);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Cria um vetor de somas e coloca a soma das linhas em cada posiçao, é isso?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

É necessário um *array* para guardar as linhas. Ele deve ter o mesmo tamanho da quantidade de linhas entradas. Não esqueça de zerar os dados. Fiz isto com [`memset()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset). E aí soma igual ao total, só que em cada elemento da linha. Depois imprime todos os elementos.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int linhas , colunas;
    printf("\nDigite o numero de linhas da matriz: ");
    scanf("%d", &linhas);
    printf("\nDigite o numero de colunas da matriz: ");
    scanf("%d", &colunas);
    float matriz[linhas][colunas];
    float soma = 0;
    float somaLinhas[linhas];
    memset(somaLinhas, 0, sizeof(somaLinhas));
    for (int linha = 0; linha < linhas; linha++) {
        for (int coluna = 0; coluna < colunas; coluna++) {
            printf("\nDigite o %d valor para a %d linha: ", coluna + 1, linha + 1);
            scanf("%f", &matriz[linha][coluna]);
            soma += matriz[linha][coluna];
            somaLinhas[linha] += matriz[linha][coluna];
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (int linha = 0; linha < linhas; linha++) {
        for (int coluna = 0; coluna < colunas; coluna++) printf("%5.2f ",matriz[linha][coluna]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    for (int linha = 0; linha < linhas; linha++) printf("\nA soma da linha %d eh %5.2f", linha, somaLinhas[linha]);
    printf("\nA soma total eh  %5.2f", soma);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/xrGf5z). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/rkialtry-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/SumLines.c).